# What is a proper size air conditioner for Texas 384 sq ft?

Tags: insulation, air-conditioning

My cabin is in north Texas (aka Hell’s Furnace) and is 16x24. I have R19 walls, R25 ceiling, and R20 floors. The walls are 2x6 and I have 7/16 OSB sheathing and Tyvek wrap between sheathing and siding. There are two high quality fiberglass doors, and 4 high quality windows, 2@ 36x48, 1@24x36, and 1@12x24. There is one bathroom 6x8 ft where the 12x24 window is. The attic is vented with a ridge vent and vents are in place under the overhangs. Interior walls are 1/2 in drywall. Ceilings are 8 feet.

So having said all that, I am probably going to buy a window unit rather than a portable. From what I hear and research, they’re just better all around.

As far as sizing the unit, the boxes say 10k BTU is appropriate, and a calculator I found said 13k, but that’s seems right for normal places, not the sweltering sauna that is the Lone Star State in the summer. I figured I’d go to 14K. Does this make sense?

Also how is the quality of the big-box window units? Especially the GE models?

Comment: Are the units in the range of 12 kBTU/h powered by 120 V or by 240 V? Do you have both available in the cabin?

Comment: @JimStewart I can install either receptacle

Comment: I moved to Dallas TX in the summer of 1952 just before I turned 8. Our house was not air conditioned and on the hotter nights my 3 years younger brother and I would be lying in bed at night sweating in oppressive heat. There was a droning attic fan pulling 90 to 95 F air through a screened window. In the following years we got some (Fedders) window units in the dining room, the den (converted screened porch), my parents bedroom, my 7 years older sister's bedroom, but none in the bedroom I shared with my younger brother. In 1960 we moved to a new ranch style house with central air. Wow!

Comment: To fully visualize your cabin and its setting would you state roughly where it is? Did you build it yourself? What is the siding material? the roofing? What kind of insulation is in the walls and ceiling? How is it heated?

Comment: With your insulation and a not so large size a window unit would be fine, I would go with 14k in my opinion it is better to be a little oversized for the really hot days, with that said I would not go huge as this would cause the unit to cycle more often and waste power and be really cold while it is running.

Comment: I think I’ll probably go ahead with a 12k because the 14k that I found is 60dB ... the 12k is 52dB which is what, 7 times quieter?

Comment: Another nice feature of modern window units is a wireless remote control. This allows mounting of the unit at a height which would be better for cooling, but would be inconvenient for making adjustments if one had to operate controls on the unit. The remotes presumably come with little wall mountable cradles which allow convenient switching off the a/c when the last person is leaving the room or the cabin.  This saves a lot on electric power consumption. I remember when living in Austin TX in the mid 1960s some people making the false claim that an a/c left on all day used less power!

Comment: Windows are what make a cabin pleasant and it is a shame to obscure one with a window a/c unit.  But putting a unit in a window is a relatively easy and quick job. Making an opening in a wall for a window unit (or slide-in) is non-trivial carpentry. If you look at the detailed specifications for a given window unit that you are considering, then it will give details of the width of opening required. Don't assume that a given window unit with a nominal width of 24" will fit in a given window described as 24" wide. The reason is that the installation reqts might require more side clearance.

Comment: If the windows in your cabin are installed so that the plane of the window is in the plane of the exterior siding, then you might have very little interference with the vents outside and so you *might* be able to install a nominal 24" wide a/c unit in a window which has 24" of width clear. you would have to look at the details of the installation instructions. Some instructions specify 2" or more on either side of the a/c unit so if that would apply, then you would need a 28" or wider window to install a nominal 24" wide ac unit, but that might be based on windows installed recessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that 12 kBTU/h would be fine even in north Texas. One interesting feature of window units is that the chilled condensed water from inside is used to cool the bottom coil of the condenser before the condensate is conducted out to the ground. (At least this was the arrangement in the early 1970s when we had a window unit in north Florida.) Central units just dump the 40 deg F condensate to a drain and so waste the cooling capacity of this chilled water.

If there is a separate bedroom, you might consider a mini-split ductless with one condenser unit supplying two air handlers. This would cost a lot more, and require professional installation, but would almost certainly use less power and cool better. They are advertised as employing "inverter technology"; some of these minisplits have a claimed SEER of 20 to 30 and they are available as heat pumps which would heat the cabin in winter. But personally given the price difference I would first try the window unit.

If you put in a window unit, you could cut a hole in a wall rather than use a window and there are even "window type" units (I think called slide-in) which are designed for this type of installation. Some window units can't be installed in a hole in a wall because the wall is so thick that it would cover the intake vents for the exterior part of the unit.

Comment: I have not seen a unit that floods the condensate over the condenser coils, this will increase the cooling but shorten the life of the condenser fins.

Comment: The old window units did not trickle the condensate over the coils, but the condensate drained from the evaporator coils into a tray and from there was conducted to and filled a second narrow shallow tray at the rear, immersing the bottom coil of the condenser. This tray had a pouring lip on one end and the condensate overflowed there and came out a tube at the back on one side. I saw this design on one unit which I had to pull out of its case. I don't know if this was a widely used feature and I should have explained that when I reported this design detail above.

Comment: A mini-split ductless would allow putting an air handler on a wall between windows without opening the wall and redoing studs. All one has to do is cut a circular 3" or 4" dia hole for the freon and condensate lines. The condensing unit can either be hung on the outside wall or put on the ground.  There are 12 kBTU/h mini-split a/c -  heat pumps available https://www.acwholesalers.com/LG-Air-Conditioners/LS120HXV-LS120HXV-12000-BTU-17-SEER-Ductless-Mini-Split-Heat-Pump/43939.ac?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhoa7o9f12QIVwws_Ch1HCgHkEAEYASAEEgK_wfD_BwE

Comment: most split systems have way smaller line sets, a 5 ton unit with a 1-1/4 suction line and a 1/2" liquid line would be way smaller even including the insulation on the suction line , not even a 10 ton commercial ice maker would require a 4" hole.

Comment: I have seen videos of the installation of these minisplits and IIRC the hole was 3" or so, but I didn't check when I wrote that and so I could be way off. The hole I described as "3" or 4" dia" is required for power  and control cables, both freon lines, and the condensate drain line. I wasn't thinking that the freon suction line would be 3". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozaw9QhxkQU

Comment: Found a video that says the hole in the wall for one system is 2.75". I never should have said 3" or 4" diameter.

Comment: I don't think that most DIYers would have the tools or expertise to install a ductless minsplit. This is far more demanding that installing a window unit. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUJMzKPwjbI